# Global Variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I am very new to Python. Not learnt classes yet. Using Python 3.2.2. Tried implement some procedural C logic. My code is spread over 2 files as follows.

### this file is called date.py

```
dd,mm,yy=0,0,0

def isValidDate(d,m,y):
    if(d>=1 and d<=31 and m>=1 and m<=12):
        dd,mm,yy=d,m,y #problem
        print(dd,mm,yy) #problem
        print(d,m,y) #problem
        return True
    else:
        return False

def printDate():
    print(dd,mm,yy) #problem
```

### this file is called module1.py

```
import date

def main():
    dd,mm,yy = 23,1,1984
    valid = date.isValidDate(dd,mm,yy) #problem
    print (valid)
    date.printDate()
    date.dd=22 #problem
    date.printDate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The lines that I have commented as "problem" are giving me problems.

When the statement in `module1.py` (which is `"date.dd=22"`) executes, the value of the global variable in `date.py` changes to `22` and stays that way.

But when I call the `isValidDate()` function, even though the test condition is passed, the assignment does not seem to be permanent. The local print statement in `isValidDate()` function shows that `"dd"` is assigned the value, but in the `main()` function the call to `printDate()` shows the original values.

What is going on?

Comment: you say that you execute `date.dd = 22` in `module1` and then call `isValidDate()`.  However, your code does not do this.  Can you post the exact code you are running and its output?

Comment: The order of the 2 statements did not matter. The main point was that my function was not editing the global variable. That problem is now solved.

Comment: On a side note, nothing in your code needs a global variable. Add parameters to your `isValidDate` function so that the caller supplies those values. Python almost never requires global variables unless you're doing something really unusual. I just searched through a hundred-thousand-line codebase I've spent the last decade developing, and found that I've used exactly one global variable (and that one could be removed if I cared to).

Comment: I just wanted to learn the concept. That is it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To assign values to a global variable in your code you've got to mark it as such, otherwise the code would be assigning to a local variable with the same name (that would be actually shadowing the global variable).

As explained in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement):

> It would be impossible to assign to a global variable without global, although free variables may refer to globals without being declared global.

Hence, to fix the problem, you'd need something like this:

```
def isValidDate(d,m,y):
    if(d>=1 and d<=31 and m>=1 and m<=12):
        global dd, mm, yy
        dd,mm,yy=d,m,y
        ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Your date.isValidDate function does not operate on the `global`variables  dd, mm, yy - it rather operates on (function) local variables with the same names.

In order for date.isValidDate to change the (module) global values of the variables you want, you have to declare them as global at the top of the function - like this:

```
def isValidDate(d,m,y):
    global dd, mm, yy
    ...
```